# Custom airflow.cfg inside official Airflow docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am running Airflow from [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) official docker-compose. I would like to hide default DAGs in the web app. Normally one can do this in airflow.cfg, how to hide default DAGs in docker-compose?

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set any option that exists in `airflow.cfg` by using environment variables following this syntax `AIRFLOW__{SECTION}__{KEY}`:

> Sets options in the Airflow configuration. This takes priority over the value in the airflow.cfg file.
> Replace the {SECTION} placeholder with any section and the {KEY} placeholder with any key in that specified section.

Check the `docker-compose.yaml` file you got from Airflow and change the value of `AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES` var to `false`, like this:

```yaml
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.1.4}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
```

Docs [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#environment-variables).